# Xcode - first upload of new build after App transfer

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, transfer, app-distribution

I recently received an app to my App Store Connect account via app transfer.

As the recipient of the transferred app I asked the original developer for the codebase and all of the assets, set the signing and capabilities to my team and, having worked on a new feature, I want to upload a new build to the existing (recently transferred) app on my account.

When I go to archive and distribute the app, Xcode asks me to create an App record. When I try to submit this (without changing the bundle identifier or SKU) it tells me:

'The app identifier cannot be registered to your development team because it is not available. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.'

From what I understand if I change the bundle id and SKU I will end up with another, distinct version of the app on App Store Connect, not what I want. What I want is to upload a new build to the existing app, so that current users of the app see no change, they just see that an update is available.

I am essentially looking for a way to upload a new build to the existing, transferred app, for the first time from my account.

Could you please help me understand the process and how I might go about achieving this. Thank you in advance.

I am on Xcode 14.2